# Short scifi novel based on albums of musician

Tags: story-identification, soft-sci-fi, dystopia, steampunk

I read a book a few years back and am trying to find it again.  This is a book that is sci-fi/fantasy with some hints of steampunk elements.  The society is a dystopian/utopia book and centers around a young boy in a small town.  The town is linked to larger cities by train.  The first half of the book is about the boy in the town and how the town is basically governed by the large city.  The boy then takes the train into the city because he needs change and wants to learn about things and why things work - which is something most of the town doesn't care about.

Now the odd part is that this sci-fi/fantasy novel is based off a series of albums done by a rock band (60's, 70's, 80's).  The song writer/lyricists got together with an author and they co-authored the book together.

Novel is in English, the protagonist is a young boy. The book came out in the last few years (2010-2018).

Comment: Since you figured the answer, you could (and should :) ) accept your own answer by clicking on the checkmark button on the left.

Answer (score 13):

I figured it out - [*Clockwork Angels: The novel*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13592828-clockwork-angels). The band was Rush.

> A remarkable collaboration that is unprecedented in its scope and realization, this exquisitely wrought novel represents an artistic project between the bestselling science fiction author Kevin J. Anderson and the multiplatinum rock band Rush.
>
> The newest album by Rush, Clockwork Angels, sets forth a story in Neil Peart’s lyrics that has been expanded by him and Anderson into this epic novel. In a young man’s quest to follow his dreams, he is caught between the grandiose forces of order and chaos. He travels across a lavish and colorful world of steampunk and alchemy with lost cities, pirates, anarchists, exotic carnivals, and a rigid Watchmaker who imposes precision on every aspect of daily life. The mind-bending story is complemented with rich paintings by the five-time Juno Award winner for Best Album Design, Hugh Syme.

[image: Clockworks Angels cover]